# cat: "Permission denied" inside a docker container for existing file with proper permissions

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and started with simple examples, but get "Permission denied":

```sh
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo docker run prakhar1989/static-site sh -c 'echo foo > delete.me;echo bar >> delete.me;ls -l;type cat;ls -l /bin/cat;echo -n "I am ";whoami;cat delete.me'
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    8 Feb 15 15:38 delete.me
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Feb 15 15:38 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 15:38 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 home
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Nov 27  2014 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 271 root root    0 Feb 15 15:38 proc
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Dec 26 11:32 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  3  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 var
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   69 Jan  3  2016 wrapper.sh
cat is /bin/cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51912 Mar 14  2015 /bin/cat
I am root
cat: delete.me: Permission denied
```

The original problem was Permission denied on `wrapper.sh` so I played around a bit to get more information on the problem.

The code and result above tells me that I can create a file named delete.me, append contents, see the file via ls, can check that cat is /bin/cat and has execute permission. I am logged in into the container as user root, but cat won't obey.

Is it a bug?

`docker info` gives:

```
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo docker info
Containers: 38
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 38
Images: 5
Server Version: 18.09.9
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
runc version: N/A
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 5.0.0-32-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu Core 16
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.08GiB
Name: x260
ID: JCNS:55GU:FMFK:GJGF:JQ2P:IMSA:JOW2:JT5L:VQOB:QG4C:2NU5:Z6DR
Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Thanks to the help of @JohnKugelman it works now.
Key thing is *not* to call

sudo snap install docker

but

***sudo apt  install docker.io***

```
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo snap remove docker
docker removed
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo docker run prakhar1989/static-site sh -c 'echo foo > delete.me;echo bar >> delete.me;ls -l;type cat;ls -l /bin/cat;echo -n "I am ";whoami;cp delete.me  newfile.del;ls -alrt'
sudo: docker: command not found
Gyro@Helper:~$ docker

Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install docker     # version 18.09.9, or


See 'snap info docker' for additional versions.

Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo apt  install docker.io
Reading package lists... Done
(stuff deleted)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...

7[0;51r8[1A[JGyro@Helper:~$ 
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo docker run prakhar1989/static-site sh -c 'echo foo > delete.me;echo bar >> delete.me;ls -l;type cat;ls -l /bin/cat;echo -n "I am ";whoami;cp delete.me  newfile.del;ls -alrt'
Unable to find image 'prakhar1989/static-site:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from prakhar1989/static-site

(download progress deleted)
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    8 Feb 15 17:16 delete.me
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Feb 15 17:16 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:16 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 home
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Nov 27  2014 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 292 root root    0 Feb 15 17:16 proc
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Dec 26 11:32 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  3  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 var
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   69 Jan  3  2016 wrapper.sh
cat is /bin/cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51912 Mar 14  2015 /bin/cat
I am root
total 84
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Nov 27  2014 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 home
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 srv
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 run
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 sbin
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 var
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   69 Jan  3  2016 wrapper.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  3  2016 usr
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Dec 26 11:32 sys
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:16 etc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Feb 15 17:16 .dockerenv
dr-xr-xr-x 290 root root    0 Feb 15 17:16 proc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Feb 15 17:16 dev
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    8 Feb 15 17:16 delete.me
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    8 Feb 15 17:16 newfile.del
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:16 .
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo docker run prakhar1989/static-site sh -c 'echo foo > delete.me;echo bar >> delete.me;ls -l;type cat;ls -l /bin/cat;echo -n "I am ";whoami;cat delete.me;ls -alrt'
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    8 Feb 15 17:17 delete.me
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Feb 15 17:17 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:17 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 home
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Nov 27  2014 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 291 root root    0 Feb 15 17:17 proc
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Dec 26 11:32 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  3  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 var
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   69 Jan  3  2016 wrapper.sh
cat is /bin/cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51912 Mar 14  2015 /bin/cat
I am root
foo
bar
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Nov 27  2014 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 home
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 26  2015 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 srv
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 run
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 sbin
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec 16  2015 var
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   69 Jan  3  2016 wrapper.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  3  2016 usr
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Dec 26 11:32 sys
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:17 etc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Feb 15 17:17 .dockerenv
dr-xr-xr-x 289 root root    0 Feb 15 17:17 proc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Feb 15 17:17 dev
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    8 Feb 15 17:17 delete.me
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 15 17:17 .
Gyro@Helper:~$ sudo docker run --rm prakhar1989/static-site
Nginx is running...
```

Comment: @ScottStensland What shell thing is it? Can you explain? It's not obvious to me what you're alluding to.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my computer. Running the docker command you posted succeeds with `I am root`, `foo`, `bar` at the end.

Comment: What's the base image for `prakhar1989/static-site`? It works for me using the ubuntu:latest image.

Comment: @Henry https://hub.docker.com/r/prakhar1989/static-site/

Comment: I wonder if AppArmor or SELinux are interfering. Try disabling them temporarily on your host machine.

Comment: Sounds like there is some hidden code *if $USER='Gyro' then do random error* ;-(

Comment: @JohnKugelman I was thinking that docker containers are shielded from the host environment, so how would settings on the host interfere with internal commands of the container?

Comment: Also it looks like you've installed Docker via `snap`. I think I've read about that being problematic (I don't remember why, though). You might try reinstalling it via Docker's package repository following the [instructions on the Docker web site](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Comment: AppArmor and SELinux can leak through. I'm vague on the details, though. I haven't personally had problems with them so I don't know *how* they interact with Docker, sorry.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes, it is located in /snap/bin/docker . So I guess the origin of trouble is ubuntu suggesting a problematic way to install docker.

Comment: The damage from snap might just be that it's not as up to date. Docker's repo will get you 19.03 versus snap's 18.09.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks a lot, a sick version is prone to sick results. It will take me some time to evaluate, though. And I hope it will cure some other oddities and problems I encountered.